# Arcpy fail to loop between files in different directories

Tags: arcpy, intersection, loop, error-000732

I want to perform a loop of intersections between different files in different directories. Here is my code:

```python
Intersects = ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5'] #Names of my files
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Mydirectory" #Directory of the files above
lands =  "C:\Anotherdirectory\Shapefile_To_Intersect.shp" #Name of the second shapefile to intersect, in another directory 
#    Where I want my output to be placed, this folder is already created and empty
out = "C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Intersects" 
for files in Intersects:
    Intersects_Names = ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5']
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([files, lands], os.path.join(out,files))
```

But this way I get the error:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset Name1 #;C:\Anotherdirectory\Shapefile_to_Intersect.shp # does not exist or is not supported.
```

What is the issue in this case? (I checked the file name and directory are correct).

Comment: Considering that you are referencing a workspace and not a gdb in a workspace, can I assume that that the Intersects files are shapefiles? In that case you have to add .shp to each file. If you are indeed working with a gdb then you have to add that to your workspace, like: "C:\Mydirectory\yourgdb.gdb"

Comment: Also, add and *r* before your paths to avoid issues with escape sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the feature classes in different directories? That is, your files are like:

```
r"C:\Mydirectory\Name1.shp"
r"C:\Mydirectory\Name2.shp"
r"C:\Anotherdirectory\Shapefile_To_Intersect.shp"
```

Instead of relying on workspaces, include the path with the name in your list. Then perform the intersect on that list. This intersects all of the layers together.

```
intersects = [r"C:\Mydirectory\Name1.shp",r"C:\Mydirectory\Name2.shp",r"C:\Mydirectory\Name3.shp",r"C:\Anotherdirectory\Shapefile_To_Intersect.shp"] 
out = "C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Intersects" 
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(files,out)
```

Doing the join doesn't really make sense for your output. Arcpy is seeing "Intersects" in your path as a feature dataset, and trying to create a featureclass within that feature dataset.

If you want the loop to create separate intersects for each of the filenames in the list:

```
out = "C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
for name in Intersects:
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([name,r"C:\Anotherdirectory\Shapefile_To_Intersect.shp" ], os.path.join(out,"intesects_"+name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"C:\Anotherdirectory\Shapefile_to_Intersect.shp", "lyr_to_Intersect")
arcpy.Intersect_analysis([files, "lyr_to_Intersect"], os.path.join(out,files))
```

as input for your Intersect_analysis.

Intersect_analysis only accepts layers or classes not shp files.

Comment: I did as you suggested me, now the final line looks like: "arcpy.Intersect_analysis([files, arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:\Anotherdirectory\Shapefile_to_Intersect.shp","lyr_to_Intersect")], os.path.join(out,files)) but I still receive the error message. In this case, it is exactly like before but in this case I have lyr_to_Intersect where previously there was Shapefile_to_Intersect. What may be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure "C:\Anotherdirectory\Shapefile_to_Intersect.sh‌​p" is not empty? and maybe you should make the feature layer before you intersect and make sure you add the r before your inputstring of the makeFeature layer!

Comment: i changed my answer like i think it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this is not the reason, I still receive the same message I reported two comments above.

Comment: MakeFeatureLayer shouldn't be necessary, (path to) shapefiles work fine with Intersect. That said, you should take care with all strings containing backslash characters. These should either be escaped `"C:\\Temp"` or prefixed with `r`: `r"C:\Temp"`. Failing to do so will cause unexpected results, e.g. `\t` becomes a tab, `\n` a newline, etcetera.